# How can I disable Save As in Ms Excel in Vb 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Uhm.. How can I disable Save As button, I can open Ms Excel through vb net but the thing is I also want to disable the 'save as' as the Ms Excel Open... Please Help me THANKS! :) But not in Macro..

Here's my code:

```
  Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

    Dim oXL As Excel.Application
    Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    ' Start Excel and get Application object.
    oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oXL.Visible = True
    oXL.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMaximized
    ' Get a new workbook.
    oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add
    oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet
```

How about disabling 'save as' ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Look into handling the BeforeSave event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If SaveAsUI Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

You *can* disable the actual button on the ribbon with RibbonX, but workarounds for the user still exist that will allow them to save.